# Sabre BFM: How to get the flight fare per person?

Tags: sabre

I'm building a web app with integrated booking engine using Sabre. I use Bargain Finder Max(REST) in searching for available flights. I successfully get available paired flights, However, the total fare given is based on total passenger. For example, I have 2 passengers, The flight fare per passenger is PHP 10,000.00 but the total fare that I was getting is PHP 20,000.00. I know that the total fare I was getting is correct. But I want to know how to get the fare of each passenger specially if the passenger type differs. For example there is 1 adult, 1 child and 1 infant passenger. How to get their individual prices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain that with the following group of arrays in the request:

```
  "AirTravelerAvail": [
    {
      "PassengerTypeQuantity": [
        {
          "Code": "ADT",
          "Quantity": 1
        },
        {
          "Code": "CNN",
          "Quantity": 1
        },
        {
          "Code": "INF",
          "Quantity": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
```

The response should have PTC_FareBreakdowns for individual pricing and ItinTotalFare for all of them combined.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, it works. But do you know how to get the fare of Senior Citizens and Person With Disabilities? Their code is SRC and PWD but still shows ADT fare

Comment: Senior Citizens and PWD fares are speecial rates for our LOCAL flights where they get 20% discount. It works on Sabre Red Workspace but I don't know how to implement it here in Web Service